# Sublime Text 3 autocomplete issue

Tags: autocomplete, sublime-text-3

I am not sure this is called an autocomplete feature but nonetheless. I used to create a new HTML container with the following:

```
"." + className + "tab"
```

So typing

```
.foo + "tab"
```

would create

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

I am not really sure what happened, but since yesterday typing the same gives me

```
.<div class="fo"></div>
```

So it puts the dot before the new container and removes the last letter from the div classname.

I really have no idea where to look at so asking here. Thanks in advance!

PS: I have Emmet installed. Uninstalling it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody faces this too, it turned out that emojies break that autocomlete thing. In specific, this  thing completely broke it down.